# Path parameter not resolved in resource method call

Tags: ballerina

I have a resource method defined for a client like the following.

```
isolated resource function get test/[string name]() returns string {
    return string `Hello ${name}`;
}
```

And I call this method from a service.

```
isolated resource function get test/[string str]() returns string {
    return clientObj->/test/str();
}
```

When I call this resource like say localhost:9090/test/John - I expect the output to be 'Hello John'. But the actual output is 'Hello str'. The path parameter str doesn't seem to be resolved. Is this the expected behavior or is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior as you have added `str` directly as the resource path segment. By default the resource path segments are converted to string. So this path is considered as `target/str`. If you want to give the value of the variable `str` then you have to call it using a computed resource access path segment i.e. surround with square brackets:

```
resource function get test/[string str]() returns string {
   // The brackets () at the end is optional if you don't have any other parameters
   return clientObj->/test/[str];
}
```

https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/http-client-path-parameter/

https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/client-class/